# Find common values in field

Tags: php, linux, shell, unix

Suppose I have 2 files with values:

FileA:

```
name        occupation      grade
ishaan      doctor          best
sinha       engineer        worst
palak       sales           good
nishant     commissioner    best
ishaan      doctor          good
palak       sales           okey
```

FileB:

```
name        grade       occupation
ishaan      best        doctor
sinha       worst       engineer
palak       good        sales
nishant     best        commissioner
ishaan      good        doctor
palak       okey        sales
```

I want to print only the common values in field Occupation in the two files using shell scripting. If you will suggest awk utility then please explain the command (with arguments) as well.

Answer (score 0):

think its not a good answer but you try this..

you run for loop fetch record and push every record in a new array using array_push();

and check if(!in_array()) not in array then show new record..

Answer (score 0):

**Print output in terminal:**

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

**Export output to a file:**

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' /local/file/path > /output/file/path
```

> **NOTE: NF** -- prints the last field. **NF-1** -- prints last field -1

Comment: thank you for the response. but it is printing all the values.. it is not giving common numbers. :( I need only the common values in these two fields.....

Comment: anyone to assist in this query??? i need to find the common values in the above mentioned rows.